# Minecraft-Can't take kit unless i'm OP (no permissions)

Tags: minecraft, pex, starter-kits

http://pastebin.com/izC5a00Q
Okay I have problems with my kit plugin.
Everything works if i'm opped buy if I'm not then I don't have permission pleese heelp

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong with this, you have permissions repeated 10+ times, you're adding the * to things you don't want it to be in... I've recreated the config and removed the unnecessary items and left what should be where.

http://pastebin.com/w9KtVvA8